# How to use LatLngBounds?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making a final requirement for our mobile application development subject and I am using gmaps, indoor maps to be exact. And I while researching about how to put my custom map in the google map. I encounter LatLngBounds. How do I use it without knowing the LatLng top, bottom, left and right values?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to know top,bottom,left and right.
You just determine two LatLang and bound the camera to them like below

```
 LatLng pickupLatLng = new LatLng(xx.xxxxxx, xx.xxxxxx);
 LatLng destinationLatLng = new LatLng(xx.xxxxxx, xx.xxxxxx);
 LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds.builder().include(pickupLatLng).include(destinationLatLng).build();
 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_camera_padding_new_bounds)));
```

Comment: i also forget to mention, i'm using a ground overly to put my custom map to google map. will this code work?